# Перевод String в массив чисел int

Tags: java, массивы

Есть ли функция, переводящая строку с численными значениями без запятой, разделенными пробелами, в массив `int`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Примерно как то так можно - рассплитить в массив строк по разделителю и преобразовать из строк в целочисленное:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

     String str = "11 34 3 45 23 5 67";
     String strArr[] = str.split(" ");
     int numArr[] = new int[strArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
            // System.out.println(numArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

В Java 8 можно сделать в одну строку:

```
String str = "11 34 3 45 23 5 67";
int[] numArr = Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```