# Создание массива чисел из строки с перечислением их значений

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Дана строка, где числа разделены пробелами:

> String s = "1 3 7 8 15";

Объявлен массив:

> int[] mass;

Вопрос: Как извлечь цифры из строки и заполнить ими массив?

Comment: разделить строку по пробелу, конвертировать полученные элементы в числа

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопросов: [Перевод String в массив чисел int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440361/); [Преобразовать строку чисел из JTextField](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1330068/); [Строка из цифр в массив типа int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226876/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. Разделяете строку с помощью метода [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Результат помещаете в массив строк.
2. Проходитесь циклом по массиву. Используете статический метод [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) из класса [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) для преобразования строк в числа. Только не забывайте ловить [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

**P.S:** код не прилагаю, ибо тут всё элементарно.